# Using Selectors as variables with addTarget

Tags: swift

I am having problems with Selectors in Swift. I have the following lines of code:

```
let actionTarget="onPress:"
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(actionTarget), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

But this generates the error:

```
! Could not find member 'TouchUpInside'
```

However this error disappears if I try:

```
button.addTarget(self, action "onPress:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

So I am assuming its not the `.TouchUpInside` that is causing me problems, but its the lack of a string literal that is causing me problems.

I have also tried:

```
let actionTarget="onPress:" as Selector
button.addTarget(self, action: actionTarget, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

But that didnt work either.

How can I supply the action with a Selector that is not a string literal, but instead stored in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "onPress:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

This one's correct -- you don't need to do anything special like Selector() to use a selector, simply using a string will do.

If your selector is stored in a variable, then use this:

```
let selector = "onPress:"
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(selector), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

The reason `as` isn't correct here is because it's used to cast from a superclass to a subclass. For example, `let p:UIView = UIButton(...)` and `p as UIButton` would work since `p` is in fact a `UIButton` instance. In this case, using `Selector( ... )` calls the appropriate Selector constructor and instantiates a new Selector from your String.